# Skip "open link in app" page when using firebase email link authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, interstitial

Is it possible to skip the following interstitial page when using Firebase Email Link Auth (passwordless)? Currently this page is shown regardless of whether the app is installed or not. I'd prefer to skip it and open the app directly if installed or else redirect to the App Store page.

[image]

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```swift
let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: linkToAppStorePage)!
actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: email, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings) { error in
  ...
}
```